# passing more than one variable from one page to another by a link

Tags: php, html

I want to pass two variable at a time from one page to another page by clicking on a link. I have a table containing student_id and department_id field. I running a while loop to pop up all the data from the table. Here, I want to pass the stu_id and dept_id from another page by clicking on the link "delete". One of them(stu_id or dept_id) separately can pass to that page, but how could pass them together in the same time. My code is below :

```
            if(isset($stu_id) || ($dept_id))
            {
                $order = "SELECT * FROM subscribed_student ORDER BY stu_id" or die (mysql_error());
                $result = mysql_query($order);  
                while($data = mysql_fetch_array($result))
                {
                echo("<tr>
                    <td style='padding:5px;'>$data[dept_id]</td>
                    <td style='padding:5px;'>$data[stu_id]</td>
                        <td style='padding:5px 10px;'>
                            <a href='subscribed_delete.php?stu_id=$row[stu_id]'>
                                Delete
                            </a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>");
```

thank you

Comment: I see that you are fetching data in a var called $data but in the a tag echo you use a var named $row.

Comment: yes, i have corrected that already.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can change this line:

```
<a href='subscribed_delete.php?stu_id=$row[stu_id]'>
```

into this one:

```
<a href='subscribed_delete.php?stu_id=$data[stu_id]&dept_id=$data[dept_id]'>
```

To add more parameters to your url, you have to separate every couple (name-value) with the `&`. Thus, you'll have something like this:

```
URL?param1=val1&param2=val2&param3=val3...
```

Comment: Why the HTML entity &amp; instead of the actual character & ?

Comment: @SebastiánGrignoli I don't know who edit my post. In my original one it was just a &.

Comment: yes, this is the solution i have tried for half an hour. Many many thanx dear Aurelio :):):)

Answer (score 1):

Change URL to:

```
subscribed_delete.php?stu_id=$row[stu_id]&amp;dept_id=$data[dept_id]
```

(Note the '&amp;', which will appear as '&' in the URL, but needs to be escaped in the HTML)

Comment: I think that the note about converting the ampersand to an HTML entity is wrong.  It is not necesary, in fact the link will not work with the HTML entity.